# How to trigger a JavaScript function on Richface's AJAX success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, richfaces

I believe there is some way to add a handler to A4J.AJAX to handle the XMLHttpRequest's onSuccess event. Just wondering how can I do that?

Tried very hard, still struggling to find a solution, btw, I am using JQuery as well.

Thank you very much for advice.

Comment: Try using oncomplete attribute

Comment: any example? oncomplete of? basically I am writing some code which extends the existing page. I need to handle the event globally (so every postback is handled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not perfect, but I think follows does what I want:

```
    // OK, I do not hack other's code, but I do if need
    var originalFinishRequest = A4J.AJAX.finishRequest;
    A4J.AJAX.finishRequest = function(C){           
        originalFinishRequest(C);
                // do your stuff here
    };
```

I have not go into all source of A4J, so this is only a quick dirty trick.